# How to return results from CQRSLite

Tags: cqrs

I have been using CQRSLite to implement CQRS pattern in my application.But I haven't figure out a method to return results from POST operation.

Can anyone help to resolve this issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It's not considered a good practice to have a return value from a command. However, an http post is a little different.

A common issue people have is knowing what the Id of something new that has just been created. I.e. If you create something but the Id is not returned because it's a CQRS command. In this type of scenario, I create the Id before I issue the command. I typically use a GUID but there are other ways to get a value. I can then pass the Id into the command and return it to the caller.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply , Can you send code sample integrate with CQRSLite or url that i can refer.